# Internet access when setting 2 NICS using Iptables

Tags: networking, internet, nic

I have set 2 NICS on ubntu. One to internet having IP `192.168.1.101`, another to LAN having IP `192.168.1.100` , and internet GW is `192.168.1.1`
My configuration is as below using Iptables:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have connected a Test PC to `192.168.1.100` port, and gave a static IP of `192.168.1.11`, and set the GW as `192.168.1.100` (also tried .1, and .101 !!)
Each PC can ping the other, but I am not able to access internet from the Test PC
Also, I am not able to ping the GW `192.168.1.1` from the Test PC.

Is there a missing configuration?

I also added : `echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Regards,
Fuad

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to do following

nic to the `internet` / eth0

```
address: 192.168.1.101
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

nic to the `lan`

```
address: 192.168.2.1
netmask: 255.255.255.0
```

pc connected from lan to

```
address: 192.168.2.100
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.2.1
```

You do, but for complete manual

Enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

After that

add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Because you router do not known for network `192.168.2.0/24` we must do `masquarade`

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

On this way traffic from `eth0` can go to rest of the network through `eth1`.